# UNABLE TO Get multiple documents from a collection FROM FIRESTORE

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have coded the below snippet from firestore site and according to my database
but the code isn`t working
i have tried too but nothing else works

the WHERE condition is the main reason isn`t working
else it works fine

```
 const test =() =>{
    try {
      dob.collection("users")
      .where("F_name", "==", true)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
    } catch{
      console.log("Erroror")
    }
  }
```

Database structure:

[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your document that you think should match this query? The IDs and field names are case sensitive. Also do get any errors in the browser console ?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection

This is the site link

and the console shows no error

Comment: A screenshot of your 'Firestore Document' from the Firebase console would help.

Comment: check the answer posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to fetch all users from the database you can just do a `get` without any query. But it's probably not what you want.

```
dob.collection("users").get()
```

If you are looking for several user name values you can use the `in` operator (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any)

```
dob.collection.where('F_name', 'in', ['asdf11', 'asdf123']).get();
```

If you are looking for users that has a provided a value for the `F_name` field, then you can use the `!=` operator: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#not_equal_

```
// If you store it as null when name is not set
dob.collection.where('F_name', '!=', null).get();

// If you store it as empty string when name is not set
dob.collection.where('F_name', '!=', '').get();
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the document data, the `F_name` field's value is a string but you are trying to find a boolean value with `where("F_name", "==", true)`.

The data type must be same when using queries. Try:

```
dob.collection("users").where("F_name", "==", "asdf11")
```

Here the value is hard-coded but even if you want to pass user's input in the query, then you can pass a variable with string value.

Comment: Brother, I want to fetch all the values in the collection

Comment: @The.Kingslayer then just don't add the query constraint with `where()`. Try `dob.collection("users").get().then((....))`

Comment: You are true about the snippet you mentioned for a selected field

Comment: i didn`t get it bro, can you please type the whole

Comment: @The.Kingslayer just remove `where("F_name", "==", "asdf11")` from your code and use `.get()`  on `.collection(...)` itself.

Comment: Bro,
 You are true, but i only want the data where the doc contains "F_name" in it...

Comment: @The.Kingslayer then try `dob.collection("users").orderBy("F_name").get()`